# Current and wattage overload

Tags: power-supply, power, current-limiting

So, I have an extension cord reel with four outlets and current overload protection can handle a total of 2500W, 110V, 20A. Im confused about those specification because they do not add up but that's what is listed. I am plugging in a total of 2289W 19.725 A and 585 V. Will this overload the the extension cord reel because the voltage is to high? I know current is the main area of concern but the voltage does not meet the spec.

Comment: Stop doing what you are doing and think hard.

Comment: @Andyaka your point is taken but I doubt if he understood enough initially to be able to think his way out of it unaided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When plugging in multiple device to a power outlet or extension cord.
(1) It is legitimate to sum the current draws.
(2) It is legitimate to sum the power consumptions.
(3) It is NOT legitimate to sum the voltage ratings.

Current and power are functions of the loads.
Voltage is a function of the power supply.
If you are drawing current and deriving power from 110 Volt mains then the voltage is 110 V. Adding multiple devices does not increase the voltage.

So

> There is a receipt machine 115v 4a 460w.
>   A tapper 115v 3.6 a 414 w.
>   A conveyor 115 v 12 a 1,380 w.
>   And a radio 120V .125A 15W.
>   The wattage of the individual components add up to 2,269 w.

As above, current and power can be summed. Voltage is the voltage that the source supplies. So here
Voltage = 115V or 110 V nominal .
Current ~~= 4 + 3.6 + 12 + 0.125 = 19.725 A
Watts = 460 + 414 + 1380 + 15 = 2269 Watts

However:

The power board ratings are rounded to multiples of 10.

> ... current overload protection can handle a total of 2500W, 110V, 20A.

110V x 20A =2200 Watt ~= 2500 W rating.
Or 2500W/110V = 22.72A ~= 25 A.

---

Comparison - ratings versus "reality". 
19.725A is lower than the 20A rating so would be alright.

2289W < 2500 W rated so also OK.

Comment: For instance there is a receipt machine 115v 4a 460w. A tapper 115v 3.6 a 414 w. A conveyor 115 v 12 a 1,380 w. And a radio 120V .125A 15W. The wattage of the individual components add up to 2,269 w. That's how I got the numbers